# Simple everyday examples to represent the concept of Quasiparticles - Bubble example

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, particle-physics, soft-question, quasiparticles

I was sawing a Youtube Video about Quasiparticles (for this topic it doesn't matter which one), but the video host present examples that were very far for being familiar to a wide audience.

In my experience as electrician, the classic quasiparticle example is the "electron hole" depicted as a positive charge that diffuse in doped semiconductor junctions.

And following this example I got this doubt:

**Could be an air bubble within water a good familiar example of a quasiparticle?**

Following the idea of the "hole" that difuse within a medium, I think it could be possible, in principle, to describe the bubble properties in a similar way as a particle: don't knowing specifically how, I imagine you could think that the bubble is a particle of negative mass, so the pressure make it going in the opposite way of the potential (as a rudimentary example).

**Or this "bubble example" is too flawed from the mathematical description view to be described as a Quasiparticle?**

Hope you could answer Why and How it could be used as a good example for a quasiparticle, or conversely, why not, explaining it with math fundaments.

PS: If you could share the math description of a bubble as a particle it would be great, since I am also interested in figuring out if it could be also an example of a particle with a negative mass (but I am doubtfull it will be, since you can push a bubble with a straw as a common particle).

Comment: There are different kinds of quasiparticles that cannot be considered by the bubble idea, but for the case of electron hole, the bubble idea is correct, and is also what is specifically encouraged in semiconductor theory.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent About those you cannot think about them as a "bubble", you are thinking in things like phonons?

Comment: I am thinking about things like polaritons. A mixture of photons and phonons, say. This kind of mixture is happening in standard renormalisation procedure of QFT i.e. in the definition of real electrons and real photons from the bare stuff written in the free particle Lagrangian.